# Ajax html response to div

Tags: ajax

Hi I am printing the ajax html response to div element and giving radio input option to select the file. after selecting the specific file the another div should show the message. but the ajax html response is not working

Jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{  
    $('#upload').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            $('#Analysis').show();
            $('#Content_column').hide();
            $('#file_list').show();
            $('#trait').show();
            $('#trait').html('Submitting...');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var $out = $('#file_list');
            $out.html('&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspFile list:');
            $out.append('<div id="list">');
            $('#list').html(data); 
            $out.append('</div>');
        }
    });
});
```

The output of this script is

```
<ul class="php-file-tree"><li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Genotypic</a><ul><input id="Penotypic" type="radio" name="uploads/Genotypic/" value="uploads/Genotypic/jquery.txt" />jquery.txt<br><input id="Penotypic" type="radio" name="uploads/Genotypic/" value="uploads/Genotypic/marker.csv" />marker.csv<br></ul></li><li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Other</a></li><li class="pft-directory"><a href="#">Penotypic</a><ul><input id="Penotypic" type="radio" name="uploads/Penotypic/" value="uploads/Penotypic/namPheno.csv" />namPheno.csv<br><input id="Penotypic" type="radio" name="uploads/Penotypic/" value="uploads/Penotypic/perl.pl" />perl.pl<br></ul></li></ul>
```

Jquery script:

```
$('#Penotypic').click(function() {
   var $out1 = $('#trait');
   $('#trait').show();
   $out1.append('Submitted...');
});
```

this is not showing anything in the div trait. may be the html response is loading as a tesxt so the #Penotypic is not recognised. please help me to fix this.
Thanku

Comment: Do you have any error in javascript console ? You don't need $ in your variables, for example use `out` instead of `$out`

Comment: No error found in the firebug. javascript is working fine. $out works at static page (without first jquery script)

Answer (score 1):

You have many inputs of `id="Penotypic"`. Make every `id` unique or use classes as function trigger.

I wouldn't use "/" in the `name` attribute. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Then try if your ajax script does work. If it doesn't work, try if it works from *static* page (don't use your first jQuery script, but it's output as a static form). You probably need to bind your event trigger. Use jQuery's [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: @ZZ-bb: thank u. .. i used the static method as u said its working fine with the same ID.

Comment: i removed the "/" in the name attribute, even i changed to unique ID also i tried $('#jquery.txt').on("click",function(event){alert("its working!!");});         still its not working

Comment: @user2251528 Try: `$(document).on('click', '#id_to_be_clicked', function(){ alert('This works.'); });` Should work just fine. If not, wrap it inside `$(document).ready(function(){  }`.

Comment: @user2251528 I'm running out of ideas. The most basic (static page) example above should work. Are you sure you have jQuery >= v.1.7? (Before 1.7 `bind()`, `delegate()` or `live()` was used.) Also update your question to include your current code so it might attract more people to answer.